# How to prevent summing linear-gradients?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have table with fixed column and fixed header. How to avoid adding two gradients if one is above another? I would like to keep there only one. Is it possible with some mix-blendings of colors? Or maybe there is another trick to avoid this issue?

It would be great if there is only CSS/HTML solution to achieve that

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse
}

td,
th {
    background: white;
    padding: 24px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
th::after {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, gray 0%, transparent 100%);
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    height: 16px;
}

th:first-child {
    z-index: 2
}

tr > td:first-child,
th:first-child {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
}
   
tr > td:first-child::before,
th:first-child::before {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, gray 0%, transparent 100%);
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table style="width: 500px">
   <thead>
      <th class="fixed">Fixed column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: when all the gradients are correctly setup summing them achieves the correct effect, so you probably have a different problem, show us the code.

Comment: @PA. I put code

Comment: Your posted snippet contained SASS, which is not (yet) valid CSS. I've converted your SASS back into valid CSS.

Comment: Do you have a _good reason_ for using `linear-gradient` on `::before` instead of using `box-shadow`?

Comment: @Dai I do not, but I don't know how to make box-shadow only for one edge

Comment: I can't offer any specific advice without knowing what visual-effect are you're trying to achieve - do you have any mock-up renderings or links to another website you're trying to copy/emulate?

Comment: @Dai the example I provided shows what I want to avoid. I want to avoid summing colors and have nice shadows/gradients when table is scrolled vertically or horizontally

Comment: I can see that - but that only tells us what you _don't want_ - not what you want: as-it-is, you cannot achieve what-you-want by using `linear-gradient` with non-opaque colours. FWIW, even if the shadows blended as-you-intend I don't think the design is "nice" as-it-is: shadows should be subtle, not thick grey bands.

Comment: @Dai I want not to have this effect I put in the picture in circle with sum of gradients when scroll

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule

```
thead {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 100;
}
```